# Extracting float from string using regex or otherwise

Tags: swift

I am trying to extract  float from a string and, for the most part, am there using the following:

```
var itemText = "2 ,,,//// \n\n\n Hello playground  .b.b.b.\n\n\n 21.30"

func searchForItemPrice(itemText: String) -> String {
    let words = itemText.characters.split{$0 == " "}.map(String.init)
    var float = [String]()

    for word in words {
        if word.isaFloat {
            float.append(word)
        }
    }

    return float.joinWithSeparator(" ")
}

extension String {
    var isaFloat: Bool {
        return rangeOfString("^[0-9]{1,}.[0-9]{1,}+$", options: .RegularExpressionSearch) != nil
    }
}
```

the problem I'm coming against is if there is a symbol or letter in front of or behind the float. Like so:

```
var itemText = "2 ,,,//// \n\n\n Hello playground  .b.b.b.\n\n\n £21.30n"
```

Any light shed on this or help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: The issue is that you use `^` and `$` in your regex pattern, so that's normal. Did you what's their purpose? `^`: asserts position at start of the string and `$`: asserts position at the end of the string, or before the line terminator right at the end of the string, so `$2` won't pass the test, nor `2n`.

Comment: I tried without them and it returns the float/double with the symbols/letters around it. So i now need to delete all symols and letters apart from "." from the string but im not sure how. Ive only been using regex for a couple days now.